# How can I see if my server uses DDRII or DDRIII RAM?

Tags: memory

I have a very newbie question.

My server is running out of RAM and it is time to add some. The is located far away, and I need to buy some RAM and drive to install it.

How can I determine, whether I need to buy DDRII or DDRIII, having only command line access via SSH? Is there some command that will print witch kind of RAM is supported by the server or I need to go and check the server physically?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, forgot to mention: I am using Ubuntu Server 9.04

Comment: If it's a known brand rather than a self built thing then crucial's memory configurator on their website works well enough. Tell it what type of server you have and it will tell you what memory you need and guarantee it will work with that kind of server if you buy it via the links on the configurator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `dmidecode` and read this information: http://linuxator.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/using-dmidecode-to-find-out-what-memory-chips-you-have/

Comment: Thank you. `dmidecode -t 2` and then googling the motherboard model name gave me the answer - mine uses DDR2

Answer (score 1):

Is this a linux system? If so:

`sudo dmidecode --type 17` (from here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-ram-speed-linux/)